# Creating a Rails forum, how would i create a sub category crud which can link through itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, forum

At the moment I have categories > posts > comments, and can CRUD the categories, within the categories I can CRUD the Posts (which are specific to categories) and within the Posts I can CRUD the comments, What I now want to be able to do is CRUD Sub-Categories within the Categories, But also CRUD Sub-Categories within Sub-Categories continuously.

So I am really not sure where to start, My thinking is I need to create a model that checks to see if there's a category_id, and if not to check the sub-category_id or something alone these lines?

Any help is appreciated.

Longshanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of there is no subcategories by itself. A sub-category is a category with a parent, and that is the clue.

First of you need to add the relation to the model:

```
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => :parent
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => :parent
```

Then in your migration:

```
  add_field :categories, :parent_id, :integer
```

And now you will have the:

```
  childrens = Category.first.children
  parent = childrens.first.parent
```

Available anywhere.

Feel free to rename the children-parent relation as you please but change everything else related.

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks a lot, I thought this may also be possible but wasn't able to explain it